# From node.js request JSON file to PHP

Tags: php, node.js, request

From node.js I would like to get JSON data from a PHP file. I thought about using the request package, but I am not sure about what to write in the PHP file in order to send the JSON back to node:

Node:

```
var request = require('request');
request
        .get('http://IP/File.php')
        .on('response', function(response) {
            data = JSON.parse(data from the php file);
        });
```

PHP:

```
$data = array('message' => 'HeLLO');
$json = json_encode($data);
when executing this, send $json to node
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to print a response from your .PHP file:

```
$data = array('message' => 'HeLLO');
$json = json_encode($data);
print_r($json);
```

javascript:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://IP/File.php', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    data = JSON.parse(body)[0];
  }
})
```

Comment: And how can I manage the json data from php in the node file?

Comment: @Nitsan:I'm getting below error using above method                                 error:null
response:[object Object]
body:Cannot GET /file.php